# Correct way of auditing Salesforce Set-up of a company

Tags: setup-audit-log

I have just taken over a Salesforce set-up for a company but the last Salesforce support company left no documentation so I am in the process of trawling through it to see what they have done.

Does Salesforce provide anything in regards to this matter? I do not want to miss anything out in my report!

Comment: There are a few native Salesforce tools and some third party ones. There is no one 'correct' way of doing this really as it depends on what you need to know. Salesforce does have the setup audit trail under Setup>Administer>Security Controls>View Setup Audit Trail. And this is a reason why you should always complete description fields on objects, fields and code.

Comment: Thanks - doesn't the audit trail start the moment you activate it and isn't retrospective? But I will be definitely be enabling it on the items that are of most importance!

Answer (score 1):

The [Setup Audit Trail](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_monitorsetup.htm) does not require enabling (unlike field history tracking) but only covers 180 days from the present date which needs to be downloaded as a .csv file.

> The setup audit trail history shows you the 20 most recent setup changes made to your org. It lists the date of the change, who made it, and what the change was. Additionally, if a delegate (such as an administrator or customer support representative) makes a setup change on behalf of an end-user, the Delegate User column shows the delegate’s username. For example, if a user grants login access to an administrator and the administrator makes a setup change, the administrator’s username is listed.

To access this go to Setup>Administer>Security Controls>View Setup Audit Trail.

The free [Schema Lister tool](http://schemalister.herokuapp.com/) allows you to download the fields on the objects in the Salesforce Org to an Excel workbook with 1 tab per object, but this can have problems on Orgs with very large amounts of configuration.

There are a number of third party tools on the AppExchange, such as [Octopus](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5cEKEAZ) , [Schema Surfer](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wZM3EAM) and [Field Trip](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HSXEEA4).

Other things that can be valuable are any business documentation such as process diagrams, user manuals and user stories if they are available

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce has released multiple documents on topic of best practices for admins, implementations and for developers as well.

Here are some of the sample links, which you can do through and create a custom check list for your own org.

http://www.salesforce.com/assets/pdf/misc/BP_Admins.pdf
http://www.salesforce.com/assets/pdf/misc/BP_Implementation.pdf

[Edit 1]: checklist for Auditing Your Salesforce Org

1. Check for REPORTS & DASHBOARDS
2. APPEXCHANGE APPS installed
3. USER PERMISSIONS
4. WORKFLOWS, VALIDATION RULES & EMAIL TEMPLATES

Ref: http://www.adminhero.com/auditing-salesforce-instance/

Comment: I think this will be a nice place for you to start: http://www.adminhero.com/auditing-salesforce-instance/

And then move on to best practices.

Comment: Link only answers are not favoured here - please add some more information about this topic in the answer - see [answer]

Answer (score 0):

A nice Appexchange tool to install when auditing a company is **Field Trip** (https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HSXEEA4)

You'll be able to see how many records have been created but the best thing is that you can see how fields of each objects are populated so you can eventually do some cleaning and identify important fields for users